# Java MongoDB Driver Connection Question

Tags: mongodb

Im using the MongoDB Java driver in a java web app. One question I want to ask is do i run Mongo.close() whenever Im doing doing a query , or can I keep it open and run other queries on it and close it when my application ends.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be able to run multiple commands against this single connection.

Some useful details from [the documentation](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Java+Tutorial#JavaTutorial-MakingAConnection).

> The Mongo object instance actually
>   represents a pool of connections to
>   the database; you will only need one
>   object of class Mongo even with
>   multiple threads.

Comment: is there anyway I can set like a max connections or something?

Comment: I think you are looking for MongoOptions "connectionsPerHost". The docs are here: http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/MongoOptions.html#connectionsPerHost I would test any of these options before rolling them out.